# "Keyboard" shows up after clicking on "allow" on contact permission

Tags: react-native, permissions, react-native-permissions

I am using "react-native-permissions" and requesting permission for CONTACTS, when the permission modal comes up and I click "allow", the keyboard shows up for no reason.

I am using this versions:

```
"react-native-permissions": "^2.2.2",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react": "16.13.1",
```

I upgrade react-native-permissions to 3.0.1 but nothing changed.

and here is how I request for permission:

```
 const requestContactPermissionIos = async () => {
  let granted = false;
  let statuses = [];
  try {
    const permissionResult = await request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.CONTACTS);
    statuses.push(permissionResult);
    granted = permissionResult === RESULTS.GRANTED;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      'requestContactPermissionIos: unable to request for contact permission',
    );
  }
  return {
    granted,
    statuses,
  };
};
```